# Realm Swift Error: Cycles containing embedded objects are not currently supported

Tags: swift, realm, cascading-deletes, realm-list, realm-embedded-object

As the error message in the title states, I have a `Realm` with nested embedded objects. That is, a parent `Object` with an `EmbeddedObject` that contains another `EmbeddedObject`.

Getting a `Realm` instance produces the following error:

> Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
>
> - Cycles containing embedded objects are not currently supported: 'ChildObject.children'

### Example

Here's an example of what this looks like:

```swift
public final class ParentObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic public var primaryKey = ""

    public let children = List<ChildObject>()

    public override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "primaryKey"
    }
}

public final class ChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    public let children = List<ChildObject>()
}

// Getting the default Realm will throw an error.
let _ = try! Realm()
```

I'm actually using a different `EmbeddedObject` for `ChildObject`'s `children` property, but it appears the issue is the same either way.

### Question

The reason I attempted this nesting of embedded objects was to avoid having to manage cascading deletes. However, I am currently stuck. Is there a alternative solution to this issue that avoids cascading deletes?

### Aside

Encoding `ChildObject`'s `children` to `Data` solves this issue, but this approach feels like a hack and is not without other issues.

I'm currently using `RealmSwift` v10.1.3.

Comment: The issue is not clear from the question. Realm fully supports embedded objects within embedded objects, and while there is an error message in the question title, it's not clear when or where the error is being generated from. Can you please update and clarify the question as what code is throwing the error and which line the error occurs on? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I updated my question to include the full error message. The error occurs when getting the default `Realm` instance. So, literally `try! Realm()` will do it. If embedded objects within embedded objects are supported, maybe you can explain the error to me? Thanks.

Comment: @Jay Problem solved. I appreciate you confirming that Realm supports embedded objects within embedded objects. That said, the error was fully reproducible using the code I provided :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out using a different `EmbeddedObject` type for the list element of `ChildObject`’s `children` property will solve this issue. The solution looks like this:

```
final class ChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    // Use `GrandChildObject` instead of `ChildObject` for `List.Element`.
    let children = List<GrandChildObject>()
}

final class GrandChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    // ...
}
```

Just make sure to avoid using the same type in `GrandChildObject`, as it seems to be a limitation of `EmbeddedObject`. For example, *don't* do this:

```
final class GrandChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    @objc dynamic var child: GrandChildObject?
}
```

Comment: Super good find. The documentation on Embedded objects is quite thin at the moment and they don't do a lot of what they should be able to do. Upvote for you!